# os.loadavg() returns different values than uptime

Tags: node.js

How come node's native os.loadavg() method returns different values than the uptime service? The 15min average is about the same (and consistently so) but the other values always seem to vary somewhat. I was under the impression that there was an underlying system utility that provided these values to both of them, so they would always be the same.

```
> os.loadavg()
[ 1.16943359375,
  1.26220703125,
  1.3076171875 ]

uptime
 9:40  up 25 mins, 5 users, load averages: 1.08 1.24 1.30
```

I'm running node v0.10.35 and Mac OS X Yosemite v10.10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Linux box, if I don't run them very close together then there's movement.  When I run them very closely together they match:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(require("os").loadavg())'; uptime
[ 0.130859375, 0.23876953125, 0.177734375 ]
 09:39:30 up 175 days, 11:52,  6 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.24, 0.18
```

Comment: hmm...I was running them a few seconds apart in separate console tabs. Considering they're averages over several minutes I'm surprised seconds between them caused any variance at all but I reproduced what you did, so that must be the answer. Thanks!